# how set selected spinner item in android studio?

Tags: android

please help me..

i want to set selected spinner item with same id..

ok, in my account page i have many address book entries..

and when i edit the address book..

i pass the id of country and state from my database to my edit page..

but my problem is i want to set selected item with same id of what i pass to edit page..

here is the code that get the info from database..

```
public void getEditAddress(){
        class DownloadJSONEditAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                /*mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();*/
                mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, null, true, false);
                mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customersid", customersid));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addressid", addressid));

                HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "editaddress.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String editaddressinforesult = null;
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    editaddressinforesult = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return editaddressinforesult;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String editaddressinforesult){
                myJSONEditAddressInfo=editaddressinforesult;

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObjshippinginfo = new JSONObject(myJSONEditAddressInfo);
                    jsonarrayEditAddressInfo = jsonObjshippinginfo.getJSONArray("editaddressinfo");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarrayEditAddressInfo.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject sp = jsonarrayEditAddressInfo.getJSONObject(i);
                        txtAddressId.setText(sp.getString("address_book_id"));
                        if(sp.getString("entry_gender").matches("m")){
                            radioMale.setChecked(true);
                            radioFemale.setChecked(false);
                        }else if(sp.getString("entry_gender").matches("f")){
                            radioMale.setChecked(false);
                            radioFemale.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        txtFname.setText(sp.getString("entry_firstname"));
                        txtLname.setText(sp.getString("entry_lastname"));
                        txtCompanyName.setText(sp.getString("entry_company"));
                        txtStreetAddress.setText(sp.getString("entry_street_address"));
                        txtAddressLine2.setText(sp.getString("entry_suburb"));
                        txtCity.setText(sp.getString("entry_city"));
                        txtPostZipCode.setText(sp.getString("entry_zip"));
                        txtNoState.setText(sp.getString("entry_state"));
                        txtCountryid.setText(sp.getString("countries_id"));
                        txtStateid.setText(sp.getString("entry_zone_id"));

                        txtDBCountryid.setText(sp.getString("countries_id"));
                        txtDBStateid.setText(sp.getString("entry_zone_id"));

                        if(sp.getString("entry_shipping_billing").matches("1")){
                            chkSetPrimary.setChecked(true);
                        }

                        getCountries(sp.getString("countries_id"), sp.getString("entry_zone_id"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Close the progressdialog
                //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        DownloadJSONEditAddress g = new DownloadJSONEditAddress();
        g.execute();
    }
```

and in this part of the code..

```
getCountries(sp.getString("countries_id"), sp.getString("entry_zone_id"));
```

i pass `countries_id` and `entry_zone_id`

now in my `getCountries` i want set selected item with same `countries_id`

```
public void getCountries(final String gcountries_id, final String gentry_zone_id) {
        class DownloadcountriesJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                /*mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                //mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();*/
                /*mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, null, true, false);
                mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);*/
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "countries.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception squish) {
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                registerJSON = result;
                countrylist = new ArrayList<String>();
                country = new ArrayList<CountryId>();
                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    JSONObject regjsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                    regjsonarray = regjsonObj.getJSONArray("countries");

                    //countrylist.add("Country");
                    for (int i = 0; i < regjsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        regjsonobject = regjsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                        CountryId countryid = new CountryId();
                        countryid.setCountryid(regjsonobject.optString("countries_id"));
                        country.add(countryid);


                        countrylist.add(regjsonobject.optString("countries_name"));
                    }

                    spinnerCountry.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.spinner_item,
                            countrylist));

                    // Spinner on item click listener
                    spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                                   View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            getStates(country.get(position).getCountryid());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        }
                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        DownloadcountriesJSON g = new DownloadcountriesJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
```

please help me..

im new to android..

sorry for my bad english.. :)

thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `country` and `countrylist` ArrayList size is same, easy way to set selected item in Spinner is: get index of `countries_id` from `country` and pass it to Spinner `setSelection` method.like:

```
int defaultSelectedIndex=0;
for (int i = 0; i < regjsonarray.length(); i++) {
   // your code here
    String strCountrie_Id=regjsonobject.optString("countries_id");
    if(strCountrie_Id.equalsIgnoreCase(gcountries_id)) 
     defaultSelectedIndex=i;                  
}
```

Use  `defaultSelectedIndex` to set selected item according to `gcountries_id` :

```
spinnerCountry.setSelection(defaultSelectedIndex);
```

Comment: @Joe: Make sure you have added `spinnerCountry.setSelection(defaultSelectedIndex);` line after  `spinnerCountry.setAdapter...`

Comment: perfect! it works.. thanks.. my wrong, i add `spinnerCountry.setSelection(defaultSelectedIndex);` at the top of setAdapter